# Javascript array push is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am stuck on why this array push will not work... any help appreciated.

```
    var addons = new Array();

    myService.addon_dependencies(arr[i]['addoncode']).then(function(dependency) {
        console.log(dependency[0].addon_depend);  //returns A6002
        addons.push(dependency[0].addon_depend);
    });

    console.log(addons); //returns []
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the addon_dependencies method is not finishing before you run `console.log`. The `then` method shows you're probably using some sort of promise framework. If you print it out in the `then` block it should work.

Comment: The `push` is in the `then` block, so the `push` is working. The second `log` statement is not, so that `log` statement is happening before the `then` block is finishing. Your `push` is working correctly, you're just not logging it at the right place. If you put the log right after the `addons.push` it will show properly.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.push` is working; your code must be executed asynchronously, hence the empty `addons`.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(addons) is executed before the item is beeing pushed into the array. So you see the empty array.
Try the console.log after you push new items into it.